# How to delegate parts of a where clause to a different area

Tags: linq, entity-framework

The particular situation I am currently trying to get around involves a bool? referencing a nullable bit field in the database. But the logic should apply to many different cases.

I am using Entity Framework and have an object with a bool? property. I am starting to write a lot of Linq around this particular property, but because Sql doesnt retrieve null values when bool? != true is written, I am finding I am writing queries that look like:

```
var Result = from f in FooList
             where f.NullableBool == false || f.NullableBool == null
             where f.Bar.Contains(SearchTerm)
             select f;
```

This isn't a massive problem, but I would really like to be able to remove the "x.NullableBool == false || x.NullableBool == false" to a different place and instead call something like:

```
var Result = from f in FooList
             where f.IsNot && f.Bar.Contains(SearchTerm)
             select f;
```

I have tried adding properties and methods of types like 'Expression < Func < Foo, bool > >', 'Func < Foo, bool >' and 'bool' to the Foo class but Linq doesn't seem to like them.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension method of `IQueryable` should work:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Foo> WhereIsNot(this IQueryable<Foo> query)
    {
        return query.Where(f => 
            f.NullableBool == false || f.NullableBool == false);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
var result = from f in FooList.WhereIsNot()
             where f.Bar.Contains(SearchTerm)
             select f;
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma, this will work for that case. But because this returns an IQueryable (and not an ObjectQuery) I can't use the rest of the extensions like Include.

Comment: @Andy: You must specify `Include` *before* the extension method call: `from f in FooList.Include("Bars").WhereIsNot()...`. You would also need that when you use a normal `Where` method because `Where` just returns an `IQueryable`.

Comment: You can always convert `IQueryable` back to `ObjectQuery` or you can install EF 4.1 and use its `Include` version working on `IQueryable` (and doing that conversion internally).

Comment: @Slauma, Yes you are right, I was having a bit of a slow moment when I looked at that. I'm a bit surprised there doesn't look like a way of getting this to work inside the query though - maybe I'm expecting it to do something it was never designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can write a simple extension method

```
public static bool IsNot (this Foo f)
{
    return f.NullableBool == false || f.NullableBool == false;
}
```

and use it like this

```
var Result = from f in FooList
         where f.IsNot() && f.Bar.Contains(SearchTerm)
         select f;
```

Comment: I'm not sure the EF LINQ provider will know what to do with `IsNot()`.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried, I have also tried adding the same content as a non-extension static method, a normal method and a property and get a similar result each time of: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNot(FooNamespace.Foo)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."